# Cannot write to registry while installing Microsoft Access 2010 - Error 1406

Tags: windows-7, installation, 64-bit, microsoft-office, microsoft-access

While installing I get an error:

[image: an error]:

> Microsoft Access 2010 encountered an error during setup.
>
> Error 1406. Setup cannot write the value to the registry key \Software\Classes\Interface{000C036F-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\ProxyStubClsid.
>
> Verify that have sufficient permissions to access the registry or contact Microsoft Product Support Services (PSS) for assitance.

I went to regedit to check on the key that the error was talking about but when I clicked on it it says file not found.

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Next time please add the error messages as text. That makes it much easier for people to help, *and* for others to find this question if they have the same problem. Success!

Answer (score 1):

Try right clicking on the installation executable and selecting "run as administrator". [This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/838687) article might help.

Comment: Nope, same error.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a long knowledge base article about this error, a bit too long to summarize here: [You receive an error message when you install an Office program or open an Office program or document](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/838687).

(If this doesn't help you, then please update your question with the steps from this article you tried, and with what results.)